# Wrong characters trying to execute a code in a remote computer in US with spanish symbols

Tags: java, linux, encoding, centos

I have the following code :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
```

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field charset0 = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
        charset0.setAccessible(true);
        charset0.set(null, null);
        System.out.println(String.format("Charset : %s", Charset.defaultCharset().displayName()));
        System.out.println(new String(args[0].getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()),Charset.defaultCharset()));

    }

}
```

I'm from México and in my local machine if I execute the code with the following argument **Avión** I get the following output:

```
Charset : UTF-8
Avión
```

But when i execute the same code in a remote machine in us with Linux and Centos I get the following response:

```
  Command:   java  Test Avión
  Response:  
    Charset : US-ASCII
    Avi??n
```

I was looking in internet and I tried to execute it like this:

```
  Command:   java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Test Avión
  Response:  
            Charset : UTF-8
            Avi��n
```

This is the output if execute the command **locale** in my computer i get the following output:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

If I execute the command **locale** in the remote computer i get the following output:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: This is more a linux related problem. Could you avoid `System.out` and write to a file? Then you can specify the encoding, say in OutputStreamWriter.

Comment: How do you connect to the remote machine?

Comment: By ussing ssh, and without System.out the problem remains